# Anything to do (besides leave) when I was brought on board because of a crush?

Tags: sexual-harassment

I met an executive at a seminar; she emailed saying she was desperate for help putting together a website, and asked for 8 hours of my time at professional rate. She also wanted it to be all a (one-on-one) meeting, which I thought odd, but I decided to go along. We met at a library at my choice.

The meeting was uncomfortable and I felt that she wasted a lot of time trying to get my attention on a personal level and like this was more about developing a personal relationship rather than a professional one.

After the meeting I realized that I was inescapably uncomfortable. When I emailed and said I was ending my involvement she asked, "Did I do something wrong?", left a voicemail, asking to talk.

What responsibilities should I, as a professional, complete before I can safely move on to other clients?

Comment: So, this person is a recruiter, not your coworker, subordinate, or manager, or contractor/contractee?

Comment: What else do you want to accomplish, besides getting out of the project?

Comment: Do you want to confront her about it? "I want to keep our relationship strictly professional."

Comment: If you are interested in the project, ignore all non business related discussions. If you are interested in "something" else, cut all ties to business and go from there.

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes here because it's fairly clear that you've already left the project (or made it pretty clear to this lady that you're leaving).  There's therefore not much of a question left to answer.

Comment: This is not sexual harassment.  Just move on.

Comment: I assume the solution asked for in my edit is what you are looking for.  If I am wrong please let me know.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I don't think that your edit matches what the OP intended. OP said that he has "set [his] phone and Gmail to block further contact attempts." This doesn't sound to me like he is interested in re-starting the project.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I read it as "I told her I'm not continuing with the project and blocked her. Is there anything else I should say/do?" It wasn't entirely clear what the OP wanted out of it, which is why it was closed. I think it should stay closed until we get clarification from the OP.

Comment: @DavidK - I reread it several times and I think you are right I think the new version is closer to what the OP was asking.

Comment: @JonathanHayward - Were you paid anything for the 8 hour meeting yet?  Did you sign any sort of agreement?  Did you intend to invoice for the 8 hour meeting if you have not been paid yet?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you've already left - you've told her already and blocked phone/email channels.

Where you go from here is up to you.  If you're having misgivings, you'll need to re-engage and you probably know where that will end up.

If you want to stay away, you just need to look for another project.

Comment: I think the OP is asking what responsibilities he has since he already took and did work from the 8 hour meeting.

Comment: Well, there is the obligation to do anything you were actually paid for, and to leave it sufficiently clean and commented that someone else can pick it up from there. (Which may take some additional work, which gets into the question of what time is billable.)  Outside of that, if you are inclined to run, you can run; if you are inclined to work you can ask to keep it professional...

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't already told her you were ending things, I would say that you should have ended things.

You could go as far as to tell her why, that it seemed like she was flirting with you and it made you uncomfortable, but I wouldn't say it's necessary.

You could even suggest that you might be up for completing the work, but that you wouldn't be comfortable meeting in person from that point on..... But if it were me I would have just left and never looked back.